# PyCharm type-hinting not working properly with stacked pytest parametrize decorators

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

Consider the following example:

`base_case.py`

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('hello')
@pytest.mark.parametrize('hi')
class BaseCase:
    @property
    def my_list(self) -> list:  # my_list should pop up on hints in a test class
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

`test_01_example.py`

```py
from base_case import BaseCase

class Test01Hello(BaseCase):
    def test_01_hi(self):
        self.  # press ctrl + space for hints
```

PyCharm fails to hint any attributes from `BaseCase` class. If I press `ctrl + space` on `self.` then the following hints from `MarkDecorator` class appear, no trace of `BaseCase`:

[image: hint annotations with stacked decorators]

By commenting one of the decorators, PyCharm is able to resolve the hints and everything works properly:

[image: hint annotations with single decorator]

I've tried creating python stub files, following [this artice](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stubs.html#create-stub-external) but without much success.

How can I instruct PyCharm that multiple `parametrize` decorators should return a decorated class and it would hint the attributes of `BaseClass` inside test class?

---

#### UPDATE

Implementing `BaseCase` in such way, makes hints to be properly resolved inside a class test but looks really wanky:

```py
import pytest


mark1 = pytest.mark.parametrize('hello')
mark2 = pytest.mark.parametrize('hi')
@mark1
@mark2
class BaseCase:
    @property
    def my_list(self) -> list:  # my_list should pop up on hints in a test class
        return [1, 2, 3]
```

I'm still looking for a proper solution